# reset form validation in bootstrap modal after clicking out

Tags: jquery

im using a custom form validation script and everything works properly, however i am trying to integrate this within the body of a bootstrap modal. It mostly works fine but just one issue with resetting the form validation.

Basically if you type inside the input field it correctly validates and the submit button becomes clickable BUT then if you click on the reset button OR if you click out of the modal the form validation stays green/valid therefore the submit is still clickable.

Is there anyway to reset the form validation so its back to the original state?

Here is a working sample for your review:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yemmLw

I tried using the following jquery to reset the form but all that does is clear the fields not the field validation

```
$("#addcontact").trigger( "reset" );
```

and

```
$('#addcontact')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by manually changing the span classes and disabling the submit button when the reset button is clicked or when modal show is called:

```
$('.input-group span.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
$('.input-group span.input-group-addon').removeClass('success').addClass('danger');

$('#addcontact').find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
```